# How to fix MySQL not running on AWS Bitnami Wordpress problem?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bitnami

I had disk storage issue on my AWS EC2 instance. To solve this problem, I wanted to increase the volume in my EC2 instance. To do so, I had to stop my instance. When I start it again, MySQL was not going back to live.

What I assume is that either I had lost some certain files or the settings has been changed after I stopped the instance. But I could not figure that out from the log file.

```
2019-04-15T17:47:01.859462Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-04-15T17:47:01.859482Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC 
atomic builtins
2019-04-15T17:47:01.859486Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-04-15T17:47:01.859490Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin 
__sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
2019-04-15T17:47:01.859494Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 
1.2.3
2019-04-15T17:47:01.859498Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-04-15T17:47:01.859718Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-04-15T17:47:01.859805Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-04-15T17:47:01.861207Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-04-15T17:47:01.862285Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-04-15T17:47:01.862812Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-04-15T17:47:01.874471Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-04-15T17:47:01.884703Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-04-15T17:47:01.884767Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-04-15T17:47:01.891352Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written. Only 458752 bytes written. Retrying for the remaining bytes.
2019-04-15T17:47:01.891379Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for writing partial data failed.
2019-04-15T17:47:01.891391Z 0 [ERROR] 2019-04-15T17:47:02.494222Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-04-15T17:47:02.494267Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-04-15T17:47:02.494273Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-04-15T17:47:02.494279Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2019-04-15T17:47:02.494282Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-04-15T17:47:02.494287Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-04-15T17:47:02.494324Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2019-04-15T17:47:02.494338Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-04-15T17:47:02.494542Z 0 [Note] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status`?
`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart mysql` works for you?

Comment: Tried it. Does not work. I can not get MySQL up and running.

Comment: Could you please try to restart the MySQL server again and edit your post to add the new lines that appear in the log file? Please note that all the lines in the log has the data when they were executed.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart mysql` worked for me